# Блокировка приложения в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Загрузил в маркет приложение-браузер на android, для открытия только одного сайта, оно и суток не продержалось, заблокировали. Не знаю, может нельзя такие приложения публиковать, по сути это просто браузер в котором показывается мобильная версия сайта. На сайте бывает и запрещённый контент, это картинки, музыка, может из-за этого?

Из-за чего именно могли заблокировать приложение?

Не хочется чтобы ещё и аккаунт заблокировали. Может нужно заголовок конкретный указать, например музыка с такого-то сайта или бесполезно?

Comment: Скорее всего (99%) вы не подтвердили, что в приложении есть запрещенный контент (18+). Google Play наказал вас за это. Тщательнее читайте вопросы перед добавлением приложения. Если бы вы ответили "Да" на вопрос "Есть ли в приложении запрещенный контент?", то ничего бы не было, приложению была бы поставлена метка 18+. Сами подумайте, метки нет, качают дети.. И??

Answer (score 1):

Google-play ооочень лояльный, но приложения такого типа пропускать смешно. Тем-более, если у Вас есть запрещенный контент.

Comment: Что такого, плохого от такого приложения, оно на внешний вид ничем не отличается от большинства приложений для музыки. Стоит попробовать 18+ поставить или опасно? Они вроде на третий раз акк блокируют. Зайцев нет, по контенту ничем не отличается, а его не блокируют, почемуто